# Handling log files across mulitple Windows Servers

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-server-2003, logging, centralized-logging

I have an application that at any time could be running on 1 of 4 **windows servers**. Hence, if I am looking for a specific log item, it could be in any of the 4 log files. What I am looking to do is find a solution where I only need to look in one place to find all of the combined logs for each of the 4 servers.

I am looking to do this without a commercial product and also would like to do so without major performance impacts.

I am using log4net to log to a specified file on the server. One solution is to route the log4net logs to MS SQL database however I am worried about performance here. Is there a way to merge the individual files independent of the log4net code?

I originally posted this question on stackoverflow and one suggestion was to
*`"Configure log4net to log to the eventlog, and configure log forwarding of the relevant events to a central log server on all 4 application servers."`*

How would I accomplish this or what other solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Consider keeping a logging solution such as log4net. It adds flexibility and you do not need to develop that utility code.

MS SQL could be a central solution. Don't worry about performance too much until you throw a large volume of log entries at it.

Graylog is another way to do central logging, free and open source. Collectors can get either Windows event logs or files, also syslog inputs. Elasticsearch based, a scale out search platform.